# Setting Hibernate Dialect not working with Spring and YML config

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

this is my config:

```
spring.jpa:
  hibernate:
    ddl-auto: update
    connection:
      charset: utf8
      useUnicode: true
  properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Based on what I found in docs and SO it should work but still new tables are create with MyISAM instead of InnoDB.

What is wrong in my config?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The property for setting the dialect is actually `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect`

Try this:

```
spring.jpa: 
  hibernate: 
    connection: 
      charset: utf8
      useUnicode: true
    ddl-auto: update
  properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

[Spring boot sample](https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples/blob/master/spring-boot-mysql-springdatajpa-hibernate/src/main/resources/application.properties) for reference

Comment: updated config per your post but still when starting app tables are created with MyISAM...

Comment: I cloned the sample project that i linked to and set the dialect to innodb since the sample used another one. Ran it and spring created the table with `Engine: InnoDB`

Answer (score 0):

Provide below change in your application.yml

spring.datasource:
url: jdbc:mysql://?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&requireSSL=false
username: 
password:

spring.jpa:
properties:
hibernate:
dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

It will work :)