# QueryException trying to insert geolocation data

Tags: mysql, jdbc, geolocation, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I'm having trouble when trying to insert an entry into a table containing geolocation data. In fact, the table only contains one geolocation column, a Point data type. I am using Java JPA and MariaDB. The weirdest part is that the code used to work, but the application is under development, and now, after a `git merge`, it does work anymore, even though none of the code related to this geolocated Entity has been modified by the merged code, so I have no idea why it does not work anymore.

The error I get is:

> 2018-12-11 03:15:21.008  WARN 16710 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1416, SQLState: 22003
>
> 2018-12-11 03:15:21.008 ERROR 16710 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : (conn:1569) Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
>
> Query is: insert into localizations (associated_user_id, city, complement, coordx, coordy, neighbourhood, number, point, public_place, public_place_type, state, zip_code, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), parameters [,'Fortaleza','',-3.7605171,-38.57384639999998,'Jóquei Clube ','2307',<bytearray:��

This <bytearray:�� should be the value of the Point field.

I am saving the data with the method below:

```
public Location addLocation(Location location){
    location.setPoint(new Point(location.getCoordX(),location.getCoordY()));
    return locationRepository.saveAndFlush(location);
}
```

Below is my application.yml, with the same configuration as before the code stopped working.

```
server.port: 8080
server.context-path: /api

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/api
    driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: root
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
      hbm2ddl.auto: update
      show_sql: true

logging:
   level: 
      org.springframework: ERROR
```

Now, I've found answers saying to using `dialect` configuration with value `org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL5InnoDBSpatialDialect`, but unfortunately that did not help me. And now I am out of ideas. I don't think the problem lies in the application.yml configuration, since the same config used to work before.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks,

**UPDATE:** Digging more, I discovered that all the tables are being created for MyISAM, not for InnoDB, and that apparently hibernate is not detecting configurations in application.yml. Spring log says:

> hibernate.properties not found
>
> Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

BTW, I was able to insert with the command below directly in the mysql console:

```
INSERT INTO location (zip_code,state,city,number,neighbourhood,public_place_type,public_place,coordx,coordy,point) 
VALUES ('60510430','ce','fortaleza','2307','jóquei','avenida','carneiro de mendonca',55.2918681,-20.9388982,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(55.2918681 -20.9388982)'));
```

But still no game when trying to use that query from Java, using a native query. Insertion is working now, but the function `ST_PointFromText('POINT (?1 ?2)')` always sets the column value to null and if I set the Point column as NOT NULL, the insertion gives "Column 'point' cannot be null". The same happens for `ST_PointFromWKB(?1,?2)` What the hell?

**UPDATE 2:** I was able to force the use of dialect MySQL5InnoDBDialect following the tip from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44472411/3435735.

But that didn't change anything, I still get null from the functions `ST_PointFromText('POINT (?1 ?2)')` and `ST_PointFromWKB(?1,?2)`. And I'm sure of passing the arguments.

---

**FINAL UPDATE:** I was able to solve this problem, although I don't know exactly how, and I have even less idea of why it was working and then stopped. But what I did was just leaving the code as it was before the problem appeared, without using native query, made sure I had loaded the lib hibernate-spatial in pom.xml, and set the config `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect` in application.yml, since  `spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect` apparently is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
This <bytearray:�� should be the value of the Point field.
```

`POINT` is a binary type.  You can't use characters; you must use some hex or some escaping mechanism.

It sounds like `git` is the center of the mangling of text.

Everybody and his kid brother want to do funny business with bytes that are not simple Ascii.  That black diamond with a question mark is a "substitution" character -- it shows up when someone expecting UTF-8 gets an encoding that is not UTF-8.  The original data is lost.

Since you have implied that the data has been passed through several hands, I can't (from here) even venture a guess as to when it was mangled.

Note in particular, that `Point` is "binary" encoding (aka "bytearray"), so something needs to be done to protect it from mangling.  Some use hex, some use Base64.  Apparently some step failed to do such, thereby letting some subsequent step throw up its UTF-8 hands and generate those characters.

Comment: Hi Rick! What do you mean, can't use characters? In fact, JPA is managing the SQL query in this case. Should I make a query manually?

Comment: @heniotierra - I added a few more paragraphs.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem, although I don't know exactly how. I mean, I just left the code as it was before the problem, made sure to load the lib hibernate-spatial, and set the config `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect` in application.yml to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`.

Comment: Thank you for the help.